# How to see what application is running from a particular memory address?

Tags: memory, windows-10, exceptions

I upgraded to Windows 10 recently and I'm getting an NBCore.exe exception box that pops up that says:

> The exception unknown software exception 0x40000015 occurred in the application at location 0x000000006F5AD67D.

It seems like a really good place to start is to find out what application is using 0x000000006F5AD67D, but I haven't found where to look.

I've looked in Task Manager and those give me IDs but not memory addresses.  I also checked System Information (*msinfo*) but physical memory locations don't seem to be in there either.  I downloaded and ran a heap memory tool but the running processes didn't coincide with that address.

Any other hints / suggestions to see what program is using that memory location?  The error message came up more than once with the same memory location in the error, so that seems to be pointing to one app as suspect.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to me from your question that the program in question is NBCore.exe. This is part of Nero, the optical media creation app.

More generally: It does not make any sense to try to identify a particular program from an address such as that. The addresses you see in such messages are always *virtual* addresses. And every process gets a new instance of the user mode virtual address space, which runs from 0 to 0x7FFF FFFFFFFF (on modern x64 Windows systems). So the address 0x00000000 6F5AD67D is not specific to any process; *every* process includes an instance of that address. (Just like the same seven-digit phone number can exist in every area code in the country.)

A formal way to say this is that addresses in that range are *implicitly qualified* by the current process context.

Of course, whether any given address is actually in use in any given process depends on what that process is doing.

The `VMmap` tool from sysinternals will let you look at an individual process and see how it is using its address space. If you use it to look at one process, and then another, you'll see the same addresses being used over and over, as described here.